# reshape2 cast data frame with some duplicate values

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I'm trying to use the reshape2 package to redistribute the columns across the top of my dataset.  I have temperature and chl-a measured twice at three sites.  However, when I melt and cast the data frame, the fun.aggregate defaults to length.  I want to preserve the original values.  Here is an example data set:

```
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
df=data.frame(site=rep(1:3,each=2),temp_2009=c(23,24,25,25,23,43),chla_2009=c(3,2,3,4,5,6),
          temp_2010=c(23,25,26,27,23,23),chla_2010=c(2,3,5,6,2,1))
df2=melt(df,id.vars=1,measure.vars=c(2:5))
df2=cbind(df2,data.frame(str_split_fixed(df2$variable,"_",2)))
df2=df2[,-2]
names(df2)[3:4]=c("variable","year")
dcast(df2,site+year~variable)
```

I think this has something to do with the way reshape2 handles duplicate values.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Generally, it's useful to write out what you think your data.frame should look like - at least the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows are being aggregated as `dcast` can't distinguish them based upon the formula provided. If you want to maintain the original values then you'll need to include a field to identify the duplicates uniquely. To continue your code...

```
df2$group <- rep(1:2,12)
dcast(df2,site+year+group~variable)
```

Clearly this code is a bit simplistic (in particular your data must be sorted by 'group' with no missing values) but it should serve to demonstrate how to preserve the original values.

Answer (score 1):

Another option trying to dcast a molten dataset with duplicate values is to get dcast to calculate a mean/median/min/max (whatever is most relevant depending on your case) to 'resolve' duplicates.

```
 dcast(df2, site+year~variable, fun.aggregate = mean)
```

Obviously that deletes (amalgamates) records - which the OP says is undesirable